# Why is BeautifulSoup not parsing all of the page's elements?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am creating an Instagram web scraper (for practice). I am using Selenium in order to work with the dynamic webpages. I load the webpage using

`driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")`

(This is a javascript DOM line running through selenium in python)

When I print the variable storing thee output for that function, I can see the tag with the class. But after I parse it in BeautifulSoup (like this: 
`soup(jspage, "html.parser")`)

and then print out the result of that, I cannot find the tag and the class anymore. If you need more details, I'd be happy to provide them, just ask.

Here is the snippet of the code where the error is occurring:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a').click()
time.sleep(5)
            jspage = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
print(jspage)
page = soup(jspage, "html.parser")
print(page)
elements = page.findAll("a", {"class":"FPmhX notranslate  _0imsa "})
print(elements)
for element in elements:
      print(elements.text)
```

The variable jspage does include the 
`FPmhX notranslate  _0imsa`
class name (just to clarify, the spaces are not typos, they're a part of the class name) whereas the page variable does not, therefore returning an empty list when printing out the elements variable. Here is the link to the page (I know there are better ways to do this, but they would all restrict me to only being able to scrape this one page) 
`https://www.instagram.com/realdonaldtrump/following/`

If you need me to post the full code, I'd be happy to do so.

**UPDATE 1:** I tried using the `lxml` parser instead of the `html.parser` for BeautifulSoup, and I got the same result.

**UPDATE 2:** I tried changing `findAll` to `find`, but I still didn't get any output. I think this proves that the problem is in this line:
`page = soup(jspage, "html.parser")`
but I don't want to color anyone's opinion.

**ANSWER:** I've posted the answer below and will accept it when I can

Comment: does the class name have empty spaces `FPmhX notranslate  _0imsa ` can you post the html code

Comment: @0m3r yes the class does have spaces in it. I assume that is the problem. If so, how can I fix it? The original HTML is from instagram so it's too long to post here.

Comment: Can you post the link

Comment: Sure. The link leads to Donald Trump's Instagram profile, but the actual HTML comes from the ```Following``` list item which opens up a dialog box. I'm trying to scrape the names of the people he follows. I want this to apply to other users too. Here is the link to his profile: ```https://www.instagram.com/realdonaldtrump/following/``` @0m3r

Comment: _I'm trying to scrape the names of the people he follows_  - this is probably being loaded via a xhr query, which you can see if you open the network tab of your browser developer tools.

Comment: @PedroLobito The purpose of doing it is to learn selenium and get better at BeautifulSoup, so I'd rather web scrape it. Is there a way you can think of to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of investigation, I came across CSS Selectors, and that they can be implemented in BeautifulSoup (and Selenium too I believe). When the class attribute of an element has spaces in it, it means that the element has multiple classes. In my case, it has three classes: `FPmhX, notranslate, _0imsa`. I simply changed this line:

`elements = page.findAll("a", {"class":"FPmhX notranslate  _0imsa "})`
to this line:

`elements = page.select(".FPmhX.notranslate._0imsa")`

Hope this was helpful!